# bat file "cannot find file to install"

Tags: batch-file

I have a little script that creates a list from a folder and allows you to select one file to install on android.

This is the code:

```
ECHO.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
set "choice_options_app="

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:-d /b C:\src\release\android\') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set options[!count!]=%%A
    set choice_options_app=!choice_options_app!!count!
)

for /L %%A in (1,1,!count!) do echo [%%A]. !options[%%A]!
echo.
choice /c:!choice_options_app! /n /m "Enter a file to load: "
adb uninstall com.heatgenius.app
adb install C:\src\release\android\!options[%errorlevel%]!
GOTO MENU
```

Now, when i select the number, it says "can't find 'C:\src\release\android\' to install" and i really don't know why.

The files in the folder are:

```
[1] 3.2.1
[2] 3.5.20
[3] 3.5.20-5
[4] 3.5.20-Analytics
```

Can it be something wrong with the filenames? i have really no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
choice /c:!choice_options_app! /n /m "Enter a file to load: "
set "selection=%errorlevel%"
adb uninstall com.heatgenius.app
adb install C:\src\release\android\!options[%selection%]!
```

If you are not using it after the `choice`, save the `%errorlevel%` value, else it will be overwritten when the `adb uninstall` is executed.